# How can I remove date exception from OpenERP?

Tags: python, odoo

I am digging through OpenERP web to find how I can remove the exception of date from it. eg I want to insert a date like `12/12/1523`. with Current functionality it will show me an error message if i will enter a date less then `1900`. I have checked it with _calendar.py, format.py, validates.py. but i didn't succeed. If anyone here can Help me through It will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Did you try searching for the text of the error message in the source code and with Google? Adding the message text to your question here might help.

Comment: Yes I did, But that doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found two problems in openerp-web:**

1 - The date control calendar is restricted and cannot go below

```
01/01/1900
```

2 - There are validation errors raised from `openerp/i18n/format.py` when
trying to save

**Point 1**, the javascript widget can be easily fixed in

```
openerp/static/calandar/calendar.js

=> find:

    param_default("range",[1900,2999])

=> and replace with:

    param_default("range",[1,2999])
```

**Point 2, replace in**

```
openerp/i18n/format.py

=> find the two occurances of:

    return time.strftime(server_format, value)

=> and replace with:

    return mx.DateTime.Date(value[0],value[1],value[2],value[3],value[4],value[5]).strftime(server_format)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message I get when entering a date in 1523 is this:

> Invalid datetime value! Year must be greater than 1899 !

If you search for that error message in the client code, you'll find this in [`client/bin/widget/view/form_gtk/calendar.py`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-client/5.0/view/head:/bin/widget/view/form_gtk/calendar.py?start_revid=1099#L234):

```
try:
    return date.strftime(DHM_FORMAT)
except ValueError:
    common.message(_('Invalid datetime value! Year must be greater than 1899 !'))
```

If you look at [the documentation for `date.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), you'll see the following:

> The exact range of years for which strftime() works also varies across platforms. Regardless of platform, years before 1900 cannot be used.

Asking Mr. Google about "python strftime 1900" finds [an issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1777412) with a patch and lots of discussion. It sounds like you have a few options:

1. Don't use dates before 1900.
2. Edit the calendar module to implement your own formatting routine instead of `strftime()`.
3. Upgrade to Python 3.2 or 3.3. (See the issue report for details of what's fixed in each version.)
4. Apply the patch to your own version of Python.